# .net - get all records from table and loop through

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to get all records from a table and loop through it.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
database.dbDataContext db = new database.dbDataContext();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<database.User> data = db.Users.ToList();

    // rows
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        // columns
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].Count; j++)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

I'm unsure about the syntax.

Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what the `User` table looks like?? What do you want to do with the data??

Comment: if all you want is records, you already doing it with your rows for loop, do you also need a loop through all the properties of the User object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just like that:

```
database.dbDataContext db = new database.dbDataContext();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(database.User user in db.Users)
    {
       // do whatever you need to do with your `User` object here.....
       // here, you have an instance of a `User` object - access its properties
       // and methods like you always would on a `User` object....
    }
}
```

Comment: because i didn't know :) Thanks, Marc!

Comment: any idea how i can loop though the fields within a row?

Comment: @n00b: you don't get a "row" (with columns) back - you get an **object** back which has properties on it - access them as `User.FirstName`, `User.LastName` and so forth. This is an **object** - not a rows/columns collection! That is of course, assuming I'm right to believe you're using Linq-to-SQL (the `dbDataContext` seems to indicate that)

Comment: i think i got it. i will submit another question in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

You're close.  You shouldn't need the internal loop.  If your code is just this:

```
database.dbDataContext db = new database.dbDataContext();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

List<database.User> data = db.Users.ToList();

 for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
 {
     var a = data[i].Field1;
     var b = data[i].Field2;    
     ...
 }
}
```

It's a little cleaner to use Marc's version of the loop, but the core is basically that the items in the list are all objects with individual properties, not an array like I assume you expected by having the inner loop there.